# In Javascript or ES6, any way to use a string as the variable name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't know who to put it but in PHP, you can

```
<?php
  $var0 = "abc";
  $var1 = "var0";
  echo $$var1;
?>
```

This will output: "abc"

Can Javascript or ES6 do something like this? (also if there is a name for this, I'd be happy to know too)

Comment: I think you need to be clearer, you can do `var var1 = var0;` there's no reason to put that in additional quotes?

Comment: You can do with `eval`, but you **don't want to**. What is [your actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: JS has objects, which should do the trick, unless you're doing something really awful.

Comment: He wants to use variable variables in javascript.

Comment: @Mihailo - he sure does, the question is why? The answer could be anything from "no" to "template literals"

Comment: This seems like the duplicate of [“Variable” variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Something like this : `var var0 = "abc"; var var1 = ${var0};`. [More information here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)

Comment: you could do something like: var a = 'text'; var b = 'a'; console.log(window[b]), or global[b], in case of node